# Classes in Swift

Tags: c++, xcode, class, swift

I am new on Swift and studying Classes. My question is related with that code;

```
  class someClass
{
    class func typeMethod(string:String) -> String
    {
        return string + "_Modified....."
    }
}

var strModify:String = "String"
someClass.typeMethod(strModify)
```

What is that? Is there any something like that in other languages like C++? and Where do we need that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a *type method* in Swift. Like a global function, but in the namespace of the class. It is called like `someClass.typeMethod()`, but without an instance of `someClass`.

The equivalent in C++ are static member functions, e.g.

```
class SomeClass {
public:
   static std::string method(const std::string& str) {
       return str + "_Modified";
   } 
};

...

std::string s = SomeClass::method("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a `class func` is like a `static method` in Java:

```
public static void staticMethod(){
}
```

The point is that you don't need to create an object of your class first before you can use it. 
So you should use class functions whenever no object needs to be constructed first.

An example would be a convert-method like `convertMilimeterToCentimeter(milimeter:Int)`. That method get the value to be converted as parameter and so the 'caller' of that method doesn't need to be an object. So you don't need to call it on an object but you can call it on the class itself:

```
YourClass.convertMilimeterToCentimeter(1000)
```

Often Util-classes have mainly static methods (Apache Commons IO for example)

So If you make a Util-class in Swift, you would use static functions most of the time because there is no need to create an object to perform the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following class:

```
class SomeClass {
    class func someClassFunction() {
    }

    func someFunction() {
    }
}
```

The difference between the two functions is the first one, with the `class` modifier is held by the class itself, whereas the second function `someFunction()` is held by an instance of a class. This changes how/when you can call them. For example with the class function, you don't need an instance to call the function:

```
SomeClass.someClassFunction()
```

But with the normal function, you do need an instance, which you create by instantiating it using `()`:

```
let foo = SomeClass()
foo.someFunction()
```

Answer (score -1):

To start with, the first line should read:

```
class SomeClass
```

Class names should be UpperCamelCase. That declares we are making a class (as opposed to a struct or enum).

```
class func typeMethod(string:String) -> String
{
    return string + "_Modified....."
}
```

This is a method on the class (as opposed to a method on an instance of the class. Functions associated with a class are called methods. Swift uses the keyword "func" for all functions and methods.

The (string:String) bit is the label and type of the function's single argument. The "-> String" bit indicates the return type of the function. By default in Swift the label of the first argument of a function is dropped with calling the function/method:

```
SomeClass.typeMethod("Hello World")
```

Notice that I use the UpperCamelCase so now it is clear to the reader that they are calling a class method not an instance method. The message is sent to the class itself and not a specific instance of the class.

Note that a class with a single class method, like this example, is rather pointless. You might as well just create a simple global function. There are a number of global function in Swift that are not related to any class, struct or enum. The countElements() is a good example of such a function.

It's also worth noting that this class does not require inheritance, which means it doesn't need to be a class, even if you didn't want a global function. It could just as easily be defined as a struct with a static function instead.

Where you would need something like this is dependent on context. This example, taken out-of-context like this, looks quite pointless other than presenting an example of what a class method looks like.

Comment: The OP clearly intended to present an example of a class method and ask why they're useful in general; s/he wasn't asking how a class named `someClass` with one method could be useful.

Comment: The initial cap in a class name is convention only—there's no actual meaning to the compiler. All types (classes, structs, enums) and protocols should have UpperCamelCase.

Comment: Of course I know it's by convention, hence the use of the "should be" as opposed to "must be." But, thanks for the clarification.